# Erro logout, não encontra classe de conexão

Tags: php

Eu tenho o seguinte código de logout:

```
<?php
    require_once 'session.php';
    require_once 'User.php';

    $user_logout = new User();
    if($user_logout->is_loggedin()!="")
    {
        $user_logout->redirect('./index.php');
    }
    if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout']=="true")
    {
        $user_logout->doLogout();
        $user_logout->redirect('../../login.php');
    }
?>
```

Onde ele faz o requerimento para classe **User.php** que guarda todas as funções do usuário. Nele existe a função **doLogout()**:

```
<?php

require_once './connect/Connect.php';

class User
{   

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;      
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function register($stName, $stUser, $stEmail, $stPhone, $stPassword, $stDepartment, $stLevel, $stAbout)
    {

        try
        {
            $new_password = password_hash($stPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                                            TB001_USUARIO 
                                            (TB001_NOME, 
                                             TB001_USUARIO, 
                                             TB001_EMAIL, 
                                             TB001_TELEFONE_1, 
                                             TB001_SENHA, 
                                             TB002_DEPARTAMENTO_CODIGO, 
                                             TB001_LEVEL, 
                                             TB001_SOBRE) 
                                          VALUES (:name, :user, :email, :phone, :password, :departments, :level, :sobre)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":name", $stName);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user", $stUser);
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $stEmail);
            $stmt->bindParam(":phone", $stPhone);
            $stmt->bindParam(":password", $new_password);
            $stmt->bindParam(":departments", $stDepartment);
            $stmt->bindparam(":level", $stLevel);
            $stmt->bindparam(":sobre", $stAbout);

            $stmt->execute();   

            return $stmt;   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }               
    }


    public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT 
                                            TB001_CODIGO, 
                                            TB001_USUARIO, 
                                            TB001_EMAIL, 
                                            TB001_SENHA 
                                          FROM 
                                            TB001_USUARIO 
                                          WHERE 
                                            TB001_USUARIO=:uname 
                                          OR 
                                            TB001_EMAIL=:umail");
            $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['TB001_SENHA']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['TB001_CODIGO'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function selectUser()
    {
        try 
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT 
                                            TB001_USUARIO.*, 
                                            TB002_DEPARTAMENTO.TB002_NOME 
                                          AS 
                                            TB002_DEPARTAMENTO_CODIGO 
                                          FROM 
                                            TB001_USUARIO 
                                          INNER JOIN 
                                            TB002_DEPARTAMENTO 
                                          ON 
                                            TB002_DEPARTAMENTO.TB002_CODIGO = TB001_USUARIO.TB002_DEPARTAMENTO_CODIGO;");           
            $stmt->execute();   

            return $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        }catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function update($usersid, $name, $user, $email, $phone, $level, $active, $departments)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE Users 
                                          SET name = :name, user = :user, email = :email, phone = :phone, level = :level, active = :active, departments = :departments 
                                          WHERE usersid = :usersid");
            $stmt->bindParam(':usersid', $_POST['usersid']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $_POST['phone']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':level', $_POST['level']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':active', $_POST['active']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':departments', $_POST['departments']);            
            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;

        }catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();          
        }
    }

    public function is_loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function doLogout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Quando clico no botão de logout apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Warning: require_once(./connect/Connect.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\onsistem\connect\User\User.php on line 3

Outra aplicação que tem o mesmo código está funcionando, está praticamente a mesma coisa, alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa ser o erro?

Comment: tens `session_start();` antes de tudo?

Comment: Posta o seu código de User.php por favor

Comment: Tem sim @Miguel

Comment: O problema aí é que o seu `require_once()` não está conseguindo encontrar o arquivo `Connect.php`, provavelmente pois `User.php` está em uma pasta diferente do outro arquivo que você mensiona estar funcionando. Para isso você deve colocar o caminho certo da pasta no `require_once()`. O comando para subir uma pasta é o `../` então caso queira subir mais uma pasta utilize `../../connect/Connect.php` e assim por diante. Lembre que você tem que fazer esse caminho percorrer a partir de onde está o arquivo que chama o require. No seu caso específico, chame o require assim: require_once('../Connect.p

Comment: De acordo com o erro, o PHP está procurando o arquivo incluído no caminho
`./connect/Connect.php`. Esse caminho é relativo ao caminho do arquivo onde ele está sendo usado, ou seja, `C:\wamp\www\onsistem\connect\User\`. Tente usar `require_once('../Connect.php');`

Comment: Alterei o post @DavidAlves

Comment: Como está o esquema de pastas do seu projeto? Pode tirar um print?